# Why doesn’t the system tell you the character limit while writing a question.

Tags: feature-request

Earlier, whenever I was about to write a post, when I was done with the title, the system would tell me that I have overshot my character limit. This was quite helpful. But after the last update, it no longer tells it to you instantly. Rather, it often waits for you to write the whole answer and then informs you ‘after’ the post have been written.

It is inconvenient to then edit the whole post so as to shorten the title, and then add the necessary details in the subtext.

It’s a minor problem, but it’s very annoying.

Comment: Yeah, good question.